# Изменить цвет текста, если фоновое изображение не белое?

Tags: html, css, css3

Я прочитал много статей об этом, но ничего не нашел подходящего, чтобы решить мою проблему.

Возможно ли каким-либо образом изменить цвет текста на основе фонового изображения с помощью `JQuery` и / или `CSS`?

Я должен сделать отзывчивый веб-сайт с этими требованиями, но застрял.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51254727/7394871

Comment: Крутяк даже ответ оккуратно перевели и перенесли)

Comment: @Broouzer King я ищу и перевожу топики с Enso, где встречаю оригинальные идеи и техники, которые будут полезны мне и надеюсь многим. Подключайтесь к этой работе. Это будет только приветствоваться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать режим смешивания. Поддержка браузерами такая же. Не применяется к `body`.

```css
body{
  margin:0;  
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#4cb29c;
  
}
div{
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #4cb29c 50%,transparent 50%);
  min-height:50vh;
}

p{  
  text-align:center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  margin:0;
}
.circle{
  color:#ee82ee;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle at 75% 0px, #fff 35%, rgba(27, 128, 0, 0.6) 35.5%),   
   url(https://picsum.photos/500/800?image=1069) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>asdas das safd gfs gsfgsdf sdf sdfs df</p>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <p>asdas das safd gfs gsfgsdf sdf sdfs df</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант. (+) Интересно было бы посмотреть, как работает на криволинейных формах, как в вопросе. Сделаете ещё вариант?  Можно отдельным ответом здесь

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , добавил вариант с радиальным градиентом и картинкой.

Answer (score 6):

Идея состоит в том, чтобы покрасить текст инвертированным фоном.

Вот идея, использующая радиальный градиент:

```css
.box {
  padding: 50px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 70% 0px, #fff 45%, purple 45.5%) fixed;
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*Должен быть тот же фон, но инвертированный цвет*/
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 70% 0px, purple 45%, #fff 45.5%) fixed;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
</div>
```

В вашем случае фон выглядит изображением, поэтому вам просто нужно найти похожий градиент, где вы можете инвертировать цвета.

Другая идея - использовать базовое изображение и добавить наложение для создания результата:

```css
.box {
  padding: 50px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle at 70% 0px, #fff 35%, rgba(27, 128, 0, 0.6) 35.5%),   
   url(https://picsum.photos/500/800?image=1069) center/cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*Должен быть тот же фон, но инвертированный цвет*/
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 70% 0px, rgba(27, 128, 0, 1) 35%, #fff 35.5%) fixed;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254788/7394871)